# Select column value if column exists in that table else create that column and set it's value to null in BigQuery

Tags: dynamic, google-bigquery

I want to select total 450 fixed columns from the table which may or may not have all 450 columns always. When it doesn't have all columns then it should create the missing column and set it's value as null.
In Sql there is a function
if exists()
But in bigquery I am unable to use it wisely.

Any suggestion will help a lot

Comment: Can you be more precise about your case ? Specifically: do you know what is the schema of the target table ? Is it only one column missing ? If so which one ? Are the names consistent ?

Comment: Thanks for the response Cylldby. My target table schema is fixed it is known also. Source table is not constant, some column are missing in source always and which columns will be missing that we don't know  . Everytime different columns are missing from source. We can do it manually but we need to automate the process of loading target table hence generic script is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume in the following that you have a *source* table (the one with potentially "missing" columns) and an existing *target* table (with the desired schema).

In order to get the information of the columns of these tables, you just need to look into the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table.
The solution below uses dynamic SQL, to 1) generate the desired SQL, 2) run it.

```
DECLARE column_selection STRING;

SET column_selection = (
    WITH column_table AS (
        SELECT
          source.column_name AS source_colum,
          tgt.column_name AS target_column
        FROM
          (SELECT
              column_name
            FROM `<yourproject>.<target_dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
            WHERE table_name='<target_table>') tgt
        LEFT JOIN
          (SELECT column_name
            FROM `<yourproject>.<source_dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
            WHERE table_name='<source_table>') source
        ON source.column_name = tgt.column_name
    )

    SELECT STRING_AGG(coalesce(source_column,
        CONCAT("NULL AS `",target_column, "`")), ", \n") AS col_selection
  FROM
    column_table
)

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  FORMAT("SELECT %s FROM `<yourproject>.<source_dataset>.<source_table>`", column_selection) ;
```

### Explanation of the steps

1. Build a `column_table` for the columns we want to query:

   a. first column containing the columns of the target table,
   b. second one containing the corresponding source columns if they exist, or `NULL` if they don't
2. Once we have this table, we can build the desired `SELECT` statement: the name of the column is it's in the source table, or if it's NOT present, we want to have in our query " **NULL AS `column_name_in_target`** "

This is expressed in the
`coalesce(source_column, CONCAT("NULL AS` ``",target_column, "``` \``")) ```

We aggregate all these statement with `STRING_AGG` into the desired column selection.

3. Final step: putting together the rest of the query ( "SELECT" + <column_selection_string> + "FROM <your_source_table>" + ...), and we can `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` it.

Comment: Awesome! Glad there was no issue. If it solves your question please remember to "accept this answer" to mark the problem solved :)