# best way to append +30 tables using sql bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 30+ tables, all with different #'s of columns.

I'm hoping to append all the tables together into 1 single table that would share the same column names

i'm having trouble with the query below. I've essentially selected the column names i want (but not all appear in each table)

```
SELECT vertical,opportunity_name, project_name_, campaign_id, agency, account_name, sub_brand, record, uuid, date, status, q1r1, q1r2, q1r3, q1r4, q1r5, q1r6, q1r7, q1r99, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6a, q6b, q7a, q7b, q8a, q8b, q9, q10, cs1, cs1r1, cs1r2, cs1r3, cs1r4, cs1r5, cs1r6, cs1r7, cs1r8, cs1r9, cs1r10, cs1r11, cs1r12, cs1r13, cs2, cs2r1, cs2r2, cs2r3, cs2r4, cs2r5, cs2r6, cs2r7, cs2r8, cs2r9, cs2r10, cs3, cs3r1, cs3r2, cs3r3, cs3r4, cs3r5, cs3r6, cs3r7, cs3r8, cs3r9, cs3r10, cs4, cs4r1, cs4r2, cs4r3, cs4r4, cs4r5, cs4r6, cs4r7, cs5, cs5r1, cs5r2, cs5r3, cs5r4, cs5r5, cs5r6, cs5r7, cs6, cs6r1, cs6r2, cs6r3, cs6r4, cs6r5, q11, q12r1, q12r2, q12r3, q12r4, q12r5, q12r6, q13r1, q13r2, q13r3, q13r4, q13r5, q13r6, q14r1, q14r2, q14r3, q14r4, q14r5, q14r6, q15r1, q15r2, q15r3, q15r4, q15r5, q15r6, q16r1, q16r2, q16r3, q16r4, q16r5, q16r6, q17, q17newr1, q17newr2, q17newr3, q17newr4, q17newr5, q17newr6, q17newr7, q18newr1, q18newr2, q18newr3, q18newr4, q18newr5, q18newr6, q18new99, q19newr1, q19newr2, q19newr3, q19newr4, q19newr5, q19newr6, q19newr7, q19newr8, q19newr9, q19newr99, q19r1, q19r2, q19r3, q19r4, q19r5, q19r6, q19r99, q20, q21, q22, q23, q24r1, q24r2, q24r3, q24r4, q24r5, q24r6, q25, q28r1, q28r2, q28r3, q28r4, q28r5, q2901r1, q2901r2, q2901r3, q2901r4, q2901r5, q2901r6, q2901r7, q2901r8, q2901r9, q2901r10, q2901r11, q2901r12, q2901r13, q2901r14, q2901r97, q29a01, q3001r1, q3001r2, q3001r3, q3001r4, q3001r5, q3001r6, q3001r7, q3001r8, q3001r9, q3001r10, q3001r11, q3001r97, q30a01, q3101r1, q3101r2, q3101r3, q3101r4, q3101r5, q3101r6, q3201r1, q3201r2, q3201r3, q3201r4, q3201r5, q2902r1, q2902r2, q2902r3, q2902r4, q2902r5, q2902r6, q2902r7, q2902r8, q2902r9, q2902r10, q2902r11, q2902r12, q2902r13, q2902r14, q2902r97, q29a02, q3002r1, q3002r2, q3002r3, q3002r4, q3002r5, q3002r6, q3002r7, q3002r8, q3002r9, q3002r10, q3002r11, q3002r97, q30a02, q3102r1, q3102r2, q3102r3, q3102r4, q3102r5, q3102r6, q3202r1, q3202r2, q3202r3, q3202r4, q3202r5, q2903r1, q2903r2, q2903r3, q2903r4, q2903r5, q2903r6, q2903r7, q2903r8, q2903r9, q2903r10, q2903r11, q2903r12, q2903r13, q2903r14, q2903r97, q29a03, q3003r1, q3003r2, q3003r3, q3003r4, q3003r5, q3003r6, q3003r7, q3003r8, q3003r9, q3003r10, q3003r11, q3003r97, q30a03, q3103r1, q3103r2, q3103r3, q3103r4, q3103r5, q3103r6, q3203r1, q3203r2, q3203r3, q3203r4, q3203r5, q2904r1, q2904r2, q2904r3, q2904r4, q2904r5, q2904r6, q2904r7, q2904r8, q2904r9, q2904r10, q2904r11, q2904r12, q2904r13, q2904r14, q2904r97, q29a04, q3004r1, q3004r2, q3004r3, q3004r4, q3004r5, q3004r6, q3004r7, q3004r8, q3004r9, q3004r10, q3004r11, q3004r97, q30a04, q3104r1, q3104r2, q3104r3, q3104r4, q3104r5, q3104r6, q3204r1, q3204r2, q3204r3, q3204r4, q3204r5, q2905r1, q2905r2, q2905r3, q2905r4, q2905r5, q2905r6, q2905r7, q2905r8, q2905r9, q2905r10, q2905r11, q2905r12, q2905r13, q2905r14, q2905r97, q29a05, q3005r1, q3005r2, q3005r3, q3005r4, q3005r5, q3005r6, q3005r7, q3005r8, q3005r9, q3005r10, q3005r11, q3005r97, q30a05, q3105r1, q3105r2, q3105r3, q3105r4, q3105r5, q3105r6, q3205r1, q3205r2, q3205r3, q3205r4, q3205r5, q33r1, q33r2, q33r3, q33r4, q33r5, q33r99, q34r1, q34r2, q34r3, q34r4, q34r5, q35, q36, q37r1, q37r2, q37r3, q37r4, q37r5, q37r6, q38r1, q38r2, q38r3, q38r4, q38r5, q38r6, q39r1, q39r2, q39r3, q39r4, q39r5, q39r6, q40r1, q40r2, q40r3, q40r4, q40r5, q40r6, q41r1, q41r2, q41r3, q41r4, q41r5, q41r6, from Table 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT vertical,opportunity_name, project_name_, campaign_id, agency, account_name, sub_brand, record, uuid, date, status, q1r1, q1r2, q1r3, q1r4, q1r5, q1r6, q1r7, q1r99, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6a, q6b, q7a, q7b, q8a, q8b, q9, q10, cs1, cs1r1, cs1r2, cs1r3, cs1r4, cs1r5, cs1r6, cs1r7, cs1r8, cs1r9, cs1r10, cs1r11, cs1r12, cs1r13, cs2, cs2r1, cs2r2, cs2r3, cs2r4, cs2r5, cs2r6, cs2r7, cs2r8, cs2r9, cs2r10, cs3, cs3r1, cs3r2, cs3r3, cs3r4, cs3r5, cs3r6, cs3r7, cs3r8, cs3r9, cs3r10, cs4, cs4r1, cs4r2, cs4r3, cs4r4, cs4r5, cs4r6, cs4r7, cs5, cs5r1, cs5r2, cs5r3, cs5r4, cs5r5, cs5r6, cs5r7, cs6, cs6r1, cs6r2, cs6r3, cs6r4, cs6r5, q11, q12r1, q12r2, q12r3, q12r4, q12r5, q12r6, q13r1, q13r2, q13r3, q13r4, q13r5, q13r6, q14r1, q14r2, q14r3, q14r4, q14r5, q14r6, q15r1, q15r2, q15r3, q15r4, q15r5, q15r6, q16r1, q16r2, q16r3, q16r4, q16r5, q16r6, q17, q17newr1, q17newr2, q17newr3, q17newr4, q17newr5, q17newr6, q17newr7, q18newr1, q18newr2, q18newr3, q18newr4, q18newr5, q18newr6, q18new99, q19newr1, q19newr2, q19newr3, q19newr4, q19newr5, q19newr6, q19newr7, q19newr8, q19newr9, q19newr99, q19r1, q19r2, q19r3, q19r4, q19r5, q19r6, q19r99, q20, q21, q22, q23, q24r1, q24r2, q24r3, q24r4, q24r5, q24r6, q25, q28r1, q28r2, q28r3, q28r4, q28r5, q2901r1, q2901r2, q2901r3, q2901r4, q2901r5, q2901r6, q2901r7, q2901r8, q2901r9, q2901r10, q2901r11, q2901r12, q2901r13, q2901r14, q2901r97, q29a01, q3001r1, q3001r2, q3001r3, q3001r4, q3001r5, q3001r6, q3001r7, q3001r8, q3001r9, q3001r10, q3001r11, q3001r97, q30a01, q3101r1, q3101r2, q3101r3, q3101r4, q3101r5, q3101r6, q3201r1, q3201r2, q3201r3, q3201r4, q3201r5, q2902r1, q2902r2, q2902r3, q2902r4, q2902r5, q2902r6, q2902r7, q2902r8, q2902r9, q2902r10, q2902r11, q2902r12, q2902r13, q2902r14, q2902r97, q29a02, q3002r1, q3002r2, q3002r3, q3002r4, q3002r5, q3002r6, q3002r7, q3002r8, q3002r9, q3002r10, q3002r11, q3002r97, q30a02, q3102r1, q3102r2, q3102r3, q3102r4, q3102r5, q3102r6, q3202r1, q3202r2, q3202r3, q3202r4, q3202r5, q2903r1, q2903r2, q2903r3, q2903r4, q2903r5, q2903r6, q2903r7, q2903r8, q2903r9, q2903r10, q2903r11, q2903r12, q2903r13, q2903r14, q2903r97, q29a03, q3003r1, q3003r2, q3003r3, q3003r4, q3003r5, q3003r6, q3003r7, q3003r8, q3003r9, q3003r10, q3003r11, q3003r97, q30a03, q3103r1, q3103r2, q3103r3, q3103r4, q3103r5, q3103r6, q3203r1, q3203r2, q3203r3, q3203r4, q3203r5, q2904r1, q2904r2, q2904r3, q2904r4, q2904r5, q2904r6, q2904r7, q2904r8, q2904r9, q2904r10, q2904r11, q2904r12, q2904r13, q2904r14, q2904r97, q29a04, q3004r1, q3004r2, q3004r3, q3004r4, q3004r5, q3004r6, q3004r7, q3004r8, q3004r9, q3004r10, q3004r11, q3004r97, q30a04, q3104r1, q3104r2, q3104r3, q3104r4, q3104r5, q3104r6, q3204r1, q3204r2, q3204r3, q3204r4, q3204r5, q2905r1, q2905r2, q2905r3, q2905r4, q2905r5, q2905r6, q2905r7, q2905r8, q2905r9, q2905r10, q2905r11, q2905r12, q2905r13, q2905r14, q2905r97, q29a05, q3005r1, q3005r2, q3005r3, q3005r4, q3005r5, q3005r6, q3005r7, q3005r8, q3005r9, q3005r10, q3005r11, q3005r97, q30a05, q3105r1, q3105r2, q3105r3, q3105r4, q3105r5, q3105r6, q3205r1, q3205r2, q3205r3, q3205r4, q3205r5, q33r1, q33r2, q33r3, q33r4, q33r5, q33r99, q34r1, q34r2, q34r3, q34r4, q34r5, q35, q36, q37r1, q37r2, q37r3, q37r4, q37r5, q37r6, q38r1, q38r2, q38r3, q38r4, q38r5, q38r6, q39r1, q39r2, q39r3, q39r4, q39r5, q39r6, q40r1, q40r2, q40r3, q40r4, q40r5, q40r6, q41r1, q41r2, q41r3, q41r4, q41r5, q41r6, from Table 2
UNION ALL 
select vertical,opportunity_name, project_name_, campaign_id, agency, account_name, sub_brand, record, uuid, date, status, q1r1, q1r2, q1r3, q1r4, q1r5, q1r6, q1r7, q1r99, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6a, q6b, q7a, q7b, q8a, q8b, q9, q10, cs1, cs1r1, cs1r2, cs1r3, cs1r4, cs1r5, cs1r6, cs1r7, cs1r8, cs1r9, cs1r10, cs1r11, cs1r12, cs1r13, cs2, cs2r1, cs2r2, cs2r3, cs2r4, cs2r5, cs2r6, cs2r7, cs2r8, cs2r9, cs2r10, cs3, cs3r1, cs3r2, cs3r3, cs3r4, cs3r5, cs3r6, cs3r7, cs3r8, cs3r9, cs3r10, cs4, cs4r1, cs4r2, cs4r3, cs4r4, cs4r5, cs4r6, cs4r7, cs5, cs5r1, cs5r2, cs5r3, cs5r4, cs5r5, cs5r6, cs5r7, cs6, cs6r1, cs6r2, cs6r3, cs6r4, cs6r5, q11, q12r1, q12r2, q12r3, q12r4, q12r5, q12r6, q13r1, q13r2, q13r3, q13r4, q13r5, q13r6, q14r1, q14r2, q14r3, q14r4, q14r5, q14r6, q15r1, q15r2, q15r3, q15r4, q15r5, q15r6, q16r1, q16r2, q16r3, q16r4, q16r5, q16r6, q17, q17newr1, q17newr2, q17newr3, q17newr4, q17newr5, q17newr6, q17newr7, q18newr1, q18newr2, q18newr3, q18newr4, q18newr5, q18newr6, q18new99, q19newr1, q19newr2, q19newr3, q19newr4, q19newr5, q19newr6, q19newr7, q19newr8, q19newr9, q19newr99, q19r1, q19r2, q19r3, q19r4, q19r5, q19r6, q19r99, q20, q21, q22, q23, q24r1, q24r2, q24r3, q24r4, q24r5, q24r6, q25, q28r1, q28r2, q28r3, q28r4, q28r5, q2901r1, q2901r2, q2901r3, q2901r4, q2901r5, q2901r6, q2901r7, q2901r8, q2901r9, q2901r10, q2901r11, q2901r12, q2901r13, q2901r14, q2901r97, q29a01, q3001r1, q3001r2, q3001r3, q3001r4, q3001r5, q3001r6, q3001r7, q3001r8, q3001r9, q3001r10, q3001r11, q3001r97, q30a01, q3101r1, q3101r2, q3101r3, q3101r4, q3101r5, q3101r6, q3201r1, q3201r2, q3201r3, q3201r4, q3201r5, q2902r1, q2902r2, q2902r3, q2902r4, q2902r5, q2902r6, q2902r7, q2902r8, q2902r9, q2902r10, q2902r11, q2902r12, q2902r13, q2902r14, q2902r97, q29a02, q3002r1, q3002r2, q3002r3, q3002r4, q3002r5, q3002r6, q3002r7, q3002r8, q3002r9, q3002r10, q3002r11, q3002r97, q30a02, q3102r1, q3102r2, q3102r3, q3102r4, q3102r5, q3102r6, q3202r1, q3202r2, q3202r3, q3202r4, q3202r5, q2903r1, q2903r2, q2903r3, q2903r4, q2903r5, q2903r6, q2903r7, q2903r8, q2903r9, q2903r10, q2903r11, q2903r12, q2903r13, q2903r14, q2903r97, q29a03, q3003r1, q3003r2, q3003r3, q3003r4, q3003r5, q3003r6, q3003r7, q3003r8, q3003r9, q3003r10, q3003r11, q3003r97, q30a03, q3103r1, q3103r2, q3103r3, q3103r4, q3103r5, q3103r6, q3203r1, q3203r2, q3203r3, q3203r4, q3203r5, q2904r1, q2904r2, q2904r3, q2904r4, q2904r5, q2904r6, q2904r7, q2904r8, q2904r9, q2904r10, q2904r11, q2904r12, q2904r13, q2904r14, q2904r97, q29a04, q3004r1, q3004r2, q3004r3, q3004r4, q3004r5, q3004r6, q3004r7, q3004r8, q3004r9, q3004r10, q3004r11, q3004r97, q30a04, q3104r1, q3104r2, q3104r3, q3104r4, q3104r5, q3104r6, q3204r1, q3204r2, q3204r3, q3204r4, q3204r5, q2905r1, q2905r2, q2905r3, q2905r4, q2905r5, q2905r6, q2905r7, q2905r8, q2905r9, q2905r10, q2905r11, q2905r12, q2905r13, q2905r14, q2905r97, q29a05, q3005r1, q3005r2, q3005r3, q3005r4, q3005r5, q3005r6, q3005r7, q3005r8, q3005r9, q3005r10, q3005r11, q3005r97, q30a05, q3105r1, q3105r2, q3105r3, q3105r4, q3105r5, q3105r6, q3205r1, q3205r2, q3205r3, q3205r4, q3205r5, q33r1, q33r2, q33r3, q33r4, q33r5, q33r99, q34r1, q34r2, q34r3, q34r4, q34r5, q35, q36, q37r1, q37r2, q37r3, q37r4, q37r5, q37r6, q38r1, q38r2, q38r3, q38r4, q38r5, q38r6, q39r1, q39r2, q39r3, q39r4, q39r5, q39r6, q40r1, q40r2, q40r3, q40r4, q40r5, q40r6, q41r1, q41r2, q41r3, q41r4, q41r5, q41r6, from Table 3
```

i'm getting the error "Unrecognized name: q6b; Did you mean q6a? at [1:194]"

I suspect where i went wrong is that i selected column names (ex: g6b) that are not in the table.

instead of getting the column names for each 30+ of my datasets and using those in the select query, can I just use some type of null/0 value for the tables that don't have the columns?

For example, if Table 1 has q1, q3, q6b and table 2 has q1, q2, q3, q6a, can i do this as my query

```
SELECT q1, 0, q3, 0, q6b from Table 1
UNION
Select q1, 2, q3, q6a, 0 from Table 2

I'm quite new to sql & never done unions before, so any help is appreciated!
```

Comment: *would that query not work* have you ran it? What happened?

Comment: it will give an error as the column doesn't exist

Comment: Just to be sure, this has nothing to do with Google's BigTable and BigQuery?

Comment: "Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL." (see: [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)) ==> Please correct the tags!  (In this case add `google-bigquery`

Comment: Maybe this question + answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71140312/select-column-value-if-column-exists-in-that-table-else-create-that-column-and-s/71175498#71175498

Answer (score 0):

You are correct when you state:

> I suspect where i went wrong is that i selected column names (ex: g6b)
> that are not in the table.

If a field doesn't exist in the table, it can't be `SELECT`ed.

In your 2nd example, you're almost at a solution, but you're currently not providing a field name for the field of 0s.

For the SQL:

```
SELECT q1, 0, q3, 0, q6b from Table 1
UNION ALL
Select q1, q2, q3, q6a, 0 from Table 2
```

I'd expect the output to look something like:

| q1 | f0_ | q3 | f1_ | q6b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 0 | ... | 0 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | 0 |

### A solution

Instead, you should label your fields. For example:

```
SELECT 
    q1, 
    0 AS q2, 
    q3, 
    0 AS q6a, 
    q6b 
FROM
    Table 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    q1, 
    q2, 
    q3, 
    q6a, 
    0 AS q6b 
FROM
    Table 2
```

I've split the fields onto new lines for visibility. For `Table 1` I've given a field name to the 2nd and 4th fields, i.e. `q2` and `q6a`. For `Table 2` I've given a field name to the 5th field, i.e. `q6b`.

Now I'd expect to see an output that looks like this:

| q1 | q2 | q3 | q6a | q6b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 0 | ... | 0 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | 0 |

It's worth noting that when you're appending tables to each other using `UNION ALL` you only need to provide a field name in the first table. The appended tables will use the field names provided in the first table, so we don't need to provide them every time.

So this should work also:

```
SELECT 
    q1, 
    0 AS q2, 
    q3, 
    0 AS q6a, 
    q6b 
FROM
    Table 1

UNION ALL

SELECT
    q1, 
    q2, 
    q3, 
    q6a, 
    0
FROM
    Table 2
```

It only impacts one field in this example, but it would also apply where there are several fields and tables.

**Note**:
As an aside, you may want to consider whether using `NULL` values might be more appropriate than 0s for a field that doesn't exist on a given table.